# How do I show all custom shortcut keys in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, application-launch

How can I see a list of all shortcut keys assigned in Windows?

I’m talking about the shortcut you can assign to launch an application by choosing its icon, going to properties, and then “Shortcut Key” usually ctrl+shift+letter or win+shift+letter.

I want to know if there are any shortcuts that I’ve assigned and forgotten about.

Comment: How have you assigned your shortcuts?

Comment: I’ve assigned them just through the properties dialogue (right click, properties).

Comment: The answer by @MiG will find such shortcuts.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not install any software. I was hoping for a powershell script or some such.

Comment: ShortcutsMan does not need installation. Just download and execute.

Answer (score 2):

I would try Nirsoft ShortcutsMan: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shman.html

It automatically highlights broken shortcuts. I don't think there's an automated way of distinguishing between default shortcuts, program assigned and self-assigned ones, but you CAN sort by **Modified Date**, which should help you identify those. The unmodified windows default shortcuts will have the oldest dates, ignoring those will make the list a lot shorter.

Comment: I have just installed a 64bit version of ShortcutsMan: It does list a lot of shortcuts for launching programs. I could not find the shortcuts as used by certain programs. I came here because I seem to have conflicting shortcuts when I am running certain tools in parallel on my Win 10. I was hoping to find unused or "free" shortcuts. ShortcutsMan does give a huge table but funny enough, the actual shortcuts are not displayed (in default mode after launching the portable app).

Comment: @MartinZaske I'm not sure if running programs (either the main program itself, or a lightweight agent running in the background) register their shortcuts with the mechanism above. ShortcutsMan only deals with global shortcuts I think.

Comment: that works like a charm!